# Children route not loading the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a router configuration using `createBrowserRouter`.
Something like below:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: '/templates',
        element: (
            <Templates />
        ),
        children: [
          {
            path: 'template-history/:templateId', // Define template-history and templateId as parameters
            element: <Reports />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  
]);
```

I need to create children to template. Like the URL will be `"http:localhost:3000/template/template-history/123"`.

issue is If I try the above url its redirecting to  http:localhost:3000/

Comment: Did you try the `children` property? https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.2/routers/create-browser-router#routes

Comment: Just add children routes to `"/templates"` like you did for `"/"`, i.e. the root. Or is the issue that `Template` is rendering descendent routes? Please [edit] to clarify what the issue is. Include a complete [mcve] if there's more relevant code you are working with.

Comment: Yes tried to add children under templates.   I tried to call URL in this way http:localhost:3000/template/template-history/1234.  if  tried to access this URL its redirecting me to localhost:3000 the root path

Comment: I have edited the question with the exact code I have in my project.

Comment: There's no `"/template"` route, so `"/template/template-history/1234"`  won't be matched. There is, however, a `"/templates"` route, with an `"s"`, so `"/templates/template-history/1234"` can be matched. Is this just a typo in your routing code, or in the post?

Comment: @DrewReese s related comments , its just a typo

Comment: Can you share this `Templates` component? Does it render an [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) for the nested routes to render out their content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257020/discussion-between-vipina-k-and-drew-reese).

Comment: http:localhost:3000/templates/template-history/123, in this case templates component below that templatehistory component is loaded in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue after Outlet is rendered is
> `"localhost:3000/templates/template-histoty/1"` this url is loading both
> templates and templates history component in the UI together.

This is how layout routes work with the `Outlet` and their nested routes. If you want `Templates` and `Reports` to render independently you'll need to make them sibling routes.

Examples:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
      {
        path: 'templates',
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Templates />,
          },
          {
            path: 'template-history/:templateId',
            element: <Reports />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
      {
        path: 'templates',
        element: <Templates />,
      },
      {
        path: 'templates/template-history/:templateId',
        element: <Reports />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```